# Remove URL from Tag

Tags: tags

I've searched Google and I can't seem to find what I hope to achieve. I'm trying to display the tags without the hyperlink, that is this:

`<a href="blalblalba.com/tag/tagname/">tagname</a>`

becomes this:

`tagname`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_the_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) codex page says

> The following example displays the tag name of each tag assigned to
>   the post (this is like using the_tags(), but without linking each tag
>   to the tag view, and using spaces instead of commas):

```
<?php $posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
} ?>
```

ever tried that? :)

Comment: damn, didnt see that i was using the_tags, ah well thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome mate. We all have our blind spots ;)

Comment: so true, especially when you get tired! take care and happy coding :D